# How large a training set do I need for an English POS tagger?

Tags: natural-language, hidden-markov-model, viterbi-algorithm

I'm trying to implement a POS tagger for English using the Viterbi algorithm on an HMM model. Right now, my results are poor and I'm not sure whether it's due to a bug or due to lack of training data. How much training data would I need to maintain, say, 80% overall accuracy on a piece of sample text?